# How do I use a boolean flag within a for loop cycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, flags

I want to call a function (displaying a modal) when a specific condition is fulfilled (two strings matching with each other).
The conditions change and are set within a for loop cycle (it loops the elements of two JSON files).

The possible conditions are three:

1) no strings typed, no match, no problem;

2) I type a string: the for loop cycle tells me that the strings don't match;

3) I type a string: the for loop cycle tells me that the strings match.

The second and third conditions are the problematic ones for they are inside the for loop cycle and I need to call a specific action for each of them, by avoiding to repeat the action for every element in the cycle when condition 2) is fulfilled.

I want to set a **boolean flag** but I'm not sure I understood how should I use it.
I created a variable outside the for loop and gave it the value "false".
Inside the for loop, I recall such a variable by giving it the value "true".
Outside the second for loop, I call it inside an if statement which calls a function to show the modal.

I wrote the following code:

```
function validateCitta() {
    $("#cercaCitta").prop("disabled", false);        
    let text = $('#inlineFormInputCitta').val();
    if (text === "") {
        $("#errorLog").show();
    }
    else {   


        var check = false;    //  I set the flag variable 


        $.ajax({
            url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                    let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
                    if (typeCity === "city") {
                        let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
                        for (let i = 0; i < json.tappe.length; i++) {
                            let tappa = json.tappe[i];
                            let city = json.tappe[i].city;
                            if (city === nameCity) {
                                console.log("JSON file has been activated");


                                check = true;  // the condition 3 is fulfilled, then I perform the action below:

                                $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");                                    
                            }    
                            else if (check){     // the condition 3 is false, the condition 2 is fullfilled, then I show the Modal:
                                $('#myModal').show();
                            }    
                            ;
                        }                           
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        })           
    }
};
```

Which is the correct way to set and call a boolean flag? 
Can you show me some examples to better understand the usage of such a particular variable and the differences between using it from scratches and within a cycle?

Comment: *"Outside the for loop, I call it inside an if statement which calls a function to show the modal."*  This is not true.  Your if check for showing the modal is inside the for loop

Comment: @Taplar there are two for loops. The condition 3 is fulfilled when 'if (city === nameCity)' is true; otherwise, if '(typeCity === "city")' is true but 'if (city === nameCity)' is not, the condition 2 only is fullfilled. Me I want to use the flag variable to distinguish the two conditions. Thank you for your comment, I edited the Question to specify it

Comment: Again, it's not outside any of the for loops.  It is nested inside the second for loop.  You need to move that if conditional outside of both for loops

Comment: Not really clear what you want - it sounds like you either need to add a `break` - or you need to move the `if(check)` outside the `for` or remove the `else` part of `else if (check)`